# Exoplayer2 never sending rtsp fetch

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, rtsp, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to fetch and display rtsp data from my localhost.
Fetching api data through 10.0.2.2 did work , but fetching the RTSP stream that is run locally through docker. Isn't receiving calls from this code:

```
val mediaSource: MediaSource = RtspMediaSource.Factory()
    .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri("rtsp://10.0.2.2:8554/test"))
// Create a player instance.
var player = ExoPlayer.Builder(mContext).build()

// Set the media source to be played.
player.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
// Prepare the player.
player.prepare()
player.play()

Greeting("test")
// Implementing ExoPlayer
AndroidView(factory = { context ->
    PlayerView(context).apply {
        player = player
    }
})
```

What am I doing wrong

Tried to fetch RTSP local livestream via Exoplayer through 10.0.2.2